# EF Core Object properties are empty after making them private

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building an application in ASP.Net Core with EF Core and an Object `Article` that contains some price-fields (mapped to a db) that may not be accessible directly. Using a nested object PriceSet, the field must be accessible This are the objects:

```cs
public class Article{
    public string ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceInclVAT { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceExclVAT { get; set; }
    public decimal FromPriceInclVAT { get; set; }
    public decimal FromPriceExclVAT { get; set; }

    public PriceSet Prices{
        get{
            return new PriceSet(PriceInclVAT, PriceExclVAT, FromPriceInclVAT, FromPriceExclVAT);
        }
    }
}

public class PriceSet{
    private decimal _priceInclVAT { get; set; }
    private decimal _priceExclVAT { get; set; }
    private decimal _fromPriceInclVAT { get; set; }
    private decimal _fromPriceExclVAT { get; set; }

    public PriceSet(decimal PriceInclVAT, decimal PriceExclVAT, decimal FromPriceInclVAT, decimal FromPriceExclVAT){
        _priceInclVAT = PriceInclVAT;
        _priceExclVAT = PriceExclVAT;
        _fromPriceInclVAT = FromPriceInclVAT;
        _fromPriceExclVAT = FromPriceExclVAT;
    }

    public GetPrice(bool includeVAT){
        return includeVAT ? _priceInclVAT : _priceExclVAT;
    }
}
```

The object `PriceSet` will be used for multiple object that contain prices. As said, I want to set the decimal price-fields of `Article` to be non-accessible directly, so I tried setting them to private:

```cs
public class Article{
    public string ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private decimal PriceInclVAT { get; set; }
    private decimal PriceExclVAT { get; set; }
    private decimal FromPriceInclVAT { get; set; }
    private decimal FromPriceExclVAT { get; set; }

    public PriceSet Prices{
        get{
            return new PriceSet(PriceInclVAT, PriceExclVAT, FromPriceInclVAT, FromPriceExclVAT);
        }
    }
}
```

But now the values aren't filled with the data from the database.

The data is filled with my DbContext:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.ArticleId);
    entity.ToTable("ARTICLE");

    entity.Property(e => e.ArticleId);
    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .HasMaxLength(64)
        .IsUnicode(false);
    entity.Property(e => e.PriceInclVAT).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 4)");
    entity.Property(e => e.PriceExclVAT).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 4)");
    entity.Property(e => e.FromPriceInclVAT).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 4)");
    entity.Property(e => e.FromPriceExclVAT).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 4)");
});
```

What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can use read only property `public decimal PriceInclVAT { get; private set; }` or [backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field)

Comment: What is not filled ? Could you show your code. You don' t need 2 classes. Just merge everything in one.

Comment: @Vernou with that read-only setting, the properties are readable directly and that is exactly what I don't want. I need a property that isn't accessible from outside. I read the backing-field page, but don't understand how that can help in my question. Could you please help me some what further?

Comment: @Sergey the private fields in Article are not filled. Well, this is just a small part of the whole code and I reuse the PriceSet class for multiple objects with prices, so I don't want to nest them. The question remains the same: I want the price-fields in Article to be non-accessible from the outside, but they must be filled from the database using EF Core.

Comment: Pls show the action where you filed prices from DB.

Comment: What class do you use to keep prices in db. Article or PriceSet?

Comment: I added the DbContext-part that maps the database to my object. PriceSet is not present in DB, only the Article

Comment: It is impossible to hide prices  properties of Article. You will not be able to get values from DB. You can only make  class Article unmapped and create a special class to map it to Article database table to get prices from db and save them back.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use [Fiel-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=fluent-api#field-only-properties):

```cs
public class Article
{
    public string ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private decimal _priceInclVAT;
    private decimal _priceExclVAT;
    private decimal _fromPriceInclVAT;
    private decimal _fromPriceExclVAT;

    public PriceSet Prices{
        get{
            return new PriceSet(_priceInclVAT, _priceExclVAT, _fromPriceInclVAT, _fromPriceExclVAT);
        }
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
            .Property("_priceInclVAT")
            .HasColumnName("PriceInclVAT");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
            .Property("_priceExclVAT")
            .HasColumnName("PriceExclVAT");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
            .Property("_fromPriceInclVAT")
            .HasColumnName("FromPriceInclVAT");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
            .Property("_fromPriceExclVAT")
            .HasColumnName("FromPriceExclVAT");
    }
}
```